# How to retrieve "ME" contact details coming in Contact list of Android phone

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app,which will use phoneOwner details(like name, phoneNo, Email Id etc) which is coming under "ME" header of Contact List.
Is there any way to get all these details?

Answer (score 0):

This code will retrive all contactDetails of all contact Inside ContactList

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textDetail;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        readContacts();
    }

    public void readContacts() {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        sb.append("your contacts");

        ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = content.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
        String phone = null;
        String emailContact = null;
        String emailType = null;
                String name = null;

        if (c.getCount() > 0) {

            while (c.moveToNext()) {

                String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    System.out.println("ContactName : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                    sb.append("\n Contact Name:" + name);

                    Cursor phoneno = content.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    while (phoneno.moveToNext()) {
                        phone = phoneno.getString(phoneno.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        sb.append("\n Phone number:" + phone);
                        System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                    }
                    phoneno.close();

                    Cursor emailid = content.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    while (emailid.moveToNext()) {

                        emailContact = emailid.getString(emailid.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        emailType = emailid.getString(emailid.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                        sb.append("\nEmail:" + emailContact + "Email type:"
                                + emailType);
                        System.out.println("Email " + emailContact
                                + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                    }
                    emailid.close();
                }

                sb.append("\n");
                sb.append("Next");
            }
            textDetail.setText(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

To retrive only one contact add line as below,

```
if(name.equals("ME"){

// whatever you want to do
}
```

It will display only that contact detail..

Comment: Hi user2664161, Thanks for your answer, But It's not the correct solution. I am not looking for contact details of an user having name "ME", I would like to fetch details of mobile owner profile details, which is coming under default header "ME" created by android. I found the solution for It, We can do it by using "ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI" uri.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null,  null, null, null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
    c.moveToFirst();
    int position = c.getPosition();
    if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
                String columnName = columnNames[j];
                System.out.println(">>"+columnName+" = "+cursorContacts.getString(cursorContacts.getColumnIndex(columnName)));
            }
           c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
```

Comment: Hope it will help others.